# Set Yii controller dynamically in unit-test

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, regression-testing, yii1.x

I'm running some unit-tests using PHPUnit, and hack my application pretty hard in those tests (no other way, old code-base). Some parts of the code-base use

```
Yii::app()->getController()->createUrl(...);
```

but in this case, there is no controller, so the test fails. Is there a way to add a dummy controller dynamically in my test? Something like

```
Yii::app()->setController($dummyController);
```

Or do I have to initiate some kind of fake routing event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
$ctrl = new CController('whatever you need for the id')
```

and use its methods. Be careful, construct method sets `id` only. You didn't provide too much code, so this is a general idea. Look inside `createUrl()` method and check if it should work.

I used this technique to render pages (and use their contents) under console enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a controller for multiple tests you can set it once in the `setUp` method.

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    Yii::app()->controller = new CController('test');
}
```

And then you can use it in your tests:

```
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(...)
```